# У Всех ли подобным образом рендерится HTML в мобильном FireFox?

Tags: android, html, firefox, css

Есть такая конструкция http://jsbin.com/opokuDOP/1/
В главном контейнере содержится контейнер с абсолютным позиционированием, в нём див с фиксированной высотой и overflow-y: scroll и далее идут элементы списка.

Проблема в том, что в мобильном FireFox(Android) при скролинге блока с элементами появляются артефакты в свойстве box-shadow. [Вот так должно быть](https://pp.vk.me/c425622/v425622527/5270/Jw90XRAUENQ.jpg), а [вот так получается](https://pp.vk.me/c425622/v425622527/5278/M7ug3z0FoQg.jpg). Вопрос - у всех ли такое и что с этим можно придумать?

В других браузерах всё нормально. Можно конечно сделать простой border-bottom. Как то можно написать о баге в Мозиллу?

```
<div>
   <div style="position: absolute;top: 53px;">
      <div style="position: relative;height: 167px;overflow-y: scroll;">
         <div style="box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #CCCCCC;height: 39px;">текст</div>
         <div style="box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #CCCCCC;height: 39px;">текст</div>
         .....
         <div style="box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #CCCCCC;height: 39px;">текст</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну хоть кто-нибудь скажите, такая же фигня или нет?

Comment: @andrew68 думаете, много кто пользуется мобильным Firefox? Или те, кто не пользуется, ринутся его устанавливать только ради вашего примера? Боюсь, ответом на оба вопроса будет "нет"

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/keph3spld13fxcd/2013-11-08%2017.19.42.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yhzllcdq9fs3xqz/2013-11-08%2017.19.51.png
вот два скрина, такая же фигня

Comment: а если пальцем поскролить список?

Comment: @DreamChild раз здесь сидят, в том числе, и веб-разработчики, то каждый уважающий себя разраб должен иметь мобильный ФФ для тестирования своих сайтов в этом браузере.

Answer (score 1):

У меня в Firefox 40 на Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini выглядит как на первой картинке ("Вот так должно быть"). Вообще, баги можно репортить в Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox%20for%20Android